# Objective C KVO, NSLog New + Old values

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsdictionary, key-value-observing, kvocontroller

I have:

```
- (void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                       ofObject:(Player *)object
                         change:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)change
                        context:(void *)context
{
    switch (object.Status)
    {
        case 0:
            NSLog(@"%ld Play" ,object.Status);
            break;
        case 1:
            NSLog(@"%ld Pause", object.Status);
            break;
        case 2:
            NSLog(@"%ld Stop", object.Status);
            break;
        case 3:
            NSLog(@"%ld RewindF", object.Status);
            break;
        case 4:
            NSLog(@"%ld RewindB", object.Status);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

And:

```
[player addObserver:classA
         forKeyPath:@"Status"
            options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld
            context:nil];
```

I want to see on screen 2 values:
`NewValueKey` and `OldValueKey` but I don't how to NSLog OldValue too.
I tried sth that

```
NSString *oldValue = [change objectForKey:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew];
```

But I got error

> "NSUInteger too String"

How to connect old and new in one NSLog :)?

Answer (score 0):

Well if you specifically want to just log out your old and new status-- you need to type cast them (Because you receive them as `NSNumber`)

Like this:

```
  NSLog(@"OLD VALUE: %@ \nNEW VALUE: %@", [[change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeOldKey] stringValue], [[change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] stringValue]);
```

Also note that you want to use the **Key** constant, e.g `NSKeyValueChangeNewKey`.  Not the option constant, e.g `NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew`

EDIT: @Joost has corrected me, `-objectForKey` returns an `NSNumber`.  So to get a string to log, you need to send that object the `-stringValue` message

Comment: You should also be checking the keyPath to ensure that the `change` dictionary contains what you think it does.  If, for example you have this object observing a separate object-- and the KVO notification gets sent, then the `NSLog` here could throw an exception if the values in the change dictionary cannot be casted into a `long`

Comment: Your **note** is actually the problem here, not the casting. Actually, the casting you propose is incorrect as `objectForKey:` returns an object, so casting to `long` is incorrect.

Comment: Ah sorry, you're right.  Brain fart.  Read his "error" and it threw me off